# what is the difference between >&2 and &>2

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stderr

Just wondering if there is any difference between:

```
  echo "running the npm patch" >&2;
```

and

```
 echo "running the npm patch" &>2;
```

I have actually never really understand that syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read the Redirection section of the manual carefully: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

---

The `cmd >&2` form is described in section "3.6.8 Duplicating File Descriptors"

```
[n]>&word
```

Here, `n` is not specified so it defaults to "1" meaning stdout: we are redirecting stdout to file descriptor "2" meaning stderr. All normal output from the command will be sent to stderr.

---

The `cmd &>2` form is described in section "3.6.4 Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error"

> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard error:
>
> ```
> &>word
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> >&word
> ```
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred. This is semantically equivalent to
>
> ```
> >word 2>&1
> ```

In this case, "word" is "2", so we have both stdout and stderr from the command being sent to a file named `2`.

```
$ sh -c 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2' &>2
$ ls -l 2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackman jackman 14 May 14 21:40 2
$ cat 2
stdout
stderr
```

---

I found this all very confusing when I was learning. Keep at it. Remember that redirections happen in strict left-to-right order. For example

```
$ sh -c 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2' >&2 2>some.file
stdout
$ cat some.file
stderr
```

Why isn't the "stdout" string sent to that file?

Going from left to right:

- `1>&2` -- I think of this as "redirect file descriptor 1 to *whatever file descriptor 2 is currently using*". Currently, fd 2 points to /dev/stderr. So now, fd 1 also points to /dev/stderr.
- `2>some.file` -- We change fd 2 to write to the named file. This does **not** alter what fd 1 is currently using.

If we were to change the **order** of the redirections, we'd get a different result:

```
$ sh -c 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2' 2>some.file >&2
$ cat some.file 
stdout
stderr
```

Because we change fd 2 *first*. *Then* redirect fd 1 to whatever fd 2 is *currently using*.

<sub>Note that my terminology is probably wrong ("point to", etc). This is how I remember how redirections work.</sub>

Comment: Please note that `&>2` is a bashism, and is in violation of the shell language spec which requires that `cmd &> word` be treated the same as `cmd & > word`.  (Running cmd asychronously, followed by a second command list that begins with a redirection.)

Comment: Is still have 1 question though. I keep seeing interactive scripts using something like `>&2 printf "something"`. Why is that even useful?

Comment: redirections can be placed anywhere in the line. Recall that the shell processes redirections before executing the command. I also put them at the end. Put them wherever is best for you.